# cannot set the picture for the contact

Tags: android

i cannot set the picture for the contact through my app. Existing image is replaced but i cannot add the picture to the new only. can any one help!!! Thanks in advance
Here is the code

```
try {

                    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, stream);

                    android.content.ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation
                            .newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);

                    builder.withSelection(
                            ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND "
                                    + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?",
                            new String[] {
                                    String.valueOf(contactId),
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE });
                    builder.withValue(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO,
                            stream.toByteArray());
                    ops.add(builder.build());

                    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY,
                            ops);

                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
case R.id.assign_contact:

            cropstatus = 2;

             filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
             + "/Noredoo/Profile Pictures/" + file.getName();

             startCropImage(filepath, 1, 1);

             Intent contactintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
             ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

             startActivityForResult(
             Intent.createChooser(contactintent, "Choose Contact"),
             PICK_CONTACT);

            return true;
```

Comment: Your code example is incomplete and poorly formatted, please improve it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation why this works and maybe what OP was doing wrong.

Comment: @Nenotlep i have received a image through wats app, i shall view that and set that image to some contact as a contact picture. but i cannot set as a contact picture. but if there is any image existing means it ll replace and set....